# Soong variable check failed in Lineage 15.1 build

Tags: android, android-source, build-error

I'm very new to building ROMs so I don't have the knowledge on how to debug build errors.

```
brunch device
including vendor/lineage/vendorsetup.sh
Looking for dependencies in device/samsung/device
Looking for dependencies in device/samsung/device-common
Looking for dependencies in kernel/samsung/msm8916
kernel/samsung/msm8916 has no additional dependencies.
Looking for dependencies in external/stlport
external/stlport has no additional dependencies.
Looking for dependencies in device/samsung/qcom-common
Looking for dependencies in hardware/samsung
Looking for dependencies in packages/resources/devicesettings
packages/resources/devicesettings has no additional dependencies.
Looking for dependencies in packages/resources/devicesettings
packages/resources/devicesettings has no additional dependencies.
Looking for dependencies in device/qcom/common
device/qcom/common has no additional dependencies.
Looking for dependencies in external/sony/boringssl-compat
external/sony/boringssl-compat has no additional dependencies.

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=8.1.0
LINEAGE_VERSION=15.1-20180821-UNOFFICIAL-device
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_device
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION=OPM1
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-29-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPM6.171019.030.H1
OUT_DIR=/home/user/Lin15.1/out
AUX_OS_VARIANT_LIST=
============================================
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=8.1.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_device
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-29-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPM6.171019.030.H1
OUT_DIR=/home/user/Lin15.1/out
============================================
ninja: no work to do.
ninja: no work to do.
/home/user/Lin15.1/out/build-lineage_device.ninja is missing, regenerating...
/home/user/Lin15.1/out/soong/make_vars-lineage_device.mk:380: warning: TARGET_GLOBAL_CFLAGS does not match between Make and Soong:
/home/user/Lin15.1/out/soong/make_vars-lineage_device.mk:380: warning: Make : -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp
/home/user/Lin15.1/out/soong/make_vars-lineage_device.mk:380: warning: Soong: -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-short-enums -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-canonical-system-headers -fno-builtin-sin -fno-strict-volatile-bitfields -DNDEBUG -g -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -fgcse-after-reload -frerun-cse-after-loop -frename-registers -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -fdebug-prefix-map=/proc/self/cwd= -fdiagnostics-color -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=date-time -mthumb-interwork -msoft-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -D__ARM_FEATURE_LPAE=1 
/home/user/Lin15.1/out/soong/make_vars-lineage_device.mk:386: warning: TARGET_GLOBAL_CPPFLAGS does not match between Make and Soong:
/home/user/Lin15.1/out/soong/make_vars-lineage_device.mk:386: warning: Make : -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp
/home/user/Lin15.1/out/soong/make_vars-lineage_device.mk:386: warning: Soong: -Wsign-promo -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
/home/user/Lin15.1/out/soong/make_vars-lineage_device.mk:696: error: Soong variable check failed.
12:31:27 ckati failed with: exit status 1
#### failed to build some targets (2 seconds) ####
```

My device isn't officially supported, but there have been unofficial versions of it in the past for both lineage 14.1 and 15.1 and all the necessary sources are available on github.

In short my question is what's gone wrong this time in the build process and how should I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Setting `TARGET_GLOBAL_CFLAGS` (or `TARGET_GLOBAL_CPPFLAGS`) is no longer supported - the build fails as a warning. Search through the device configuration where it is being set and remove the line.

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/mVUuVazMf8k for some discussion on it.